# Compare 2 array and fetch unequal field

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
let arr1=[1,2,3]
let arr2=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to compare 2 array and obtain the array list which is not in `arr1`

i.e output as `arr3=[4,5,6]`

Approaches using lodash/Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use diffrence method from lodash

```
 _.difference([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: thnx this was quite simple

Comment: Cool..Accept the solution so that others also get benefit.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1=[1,2,3];
const arr2=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
const intersection = arr2.filter(elm => !arr1.includes(elm));
console.log(intersection);
```